# Declaring a variable then changing it with an if statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Is it necessary to add an if/else statement when declaring a variable within a function? Can I just set the variable first and then change it if a condition is met?

```
function doSomething() {
  var a = 1;
  if(something) {
    a = 2;
  }
}
```

vs

```
function doSomething() {
  var a;
  if(something) {
    a = 2;
  } else {
    a = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Flip the question: why *wouldn't* it work? All the machine does is what you tell it to--what happened when you tried it?

Comment: (Unrelated, but a few people are suggesting the conditional operator ("ternary") but... meh. Especially when starting out, IMO a simple `if` statement is sufficient.)

Comment: They both seem to work fine - I was just wondering if there were any performance implications or future issues with setting the variable twice - once on initialization and again if the condition was true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that (technically). Regarding understanding or code complexity, keep it as simple as possible.

I think your intentions would be even clearer if you used the conditional operator:

```
var a = something ? 2 : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary, as long as evaluating the second value in the initialisation has no side effects (in your case, the literal `1`, it has none).

However, using if-else might show your intention better and make the code cleaner; though that is more a matter of style than functionality. Personally I would even prefer a conditional expression:

```
var a = condition ? 2 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that - even shorter like this

```
var a = 1;
if (something) a = 2;
```

Comment: Except you should never omit block braces, of course!  (If you want to write it on one line, write `if (something) { a = 2; }`.)

Comment: There's no reason to always put a block in braces. I'd never put the statement on the same line as the if though, except under very special circumstances.

Comment: @blm If you *don't* put it on the same line you probably *should* use curly braces, though; poor indentation hygiene and "but I mean that to be in the conditional code" is *all* too easy. Particularly for beginners.

Comment: @blm [There are plenty of reasons.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6970873/501250) There's technically no reason to use any newlines either, but we do it so that we can maintain our programs.

Comment: (I didn't downvote, though; nothing wrong with showing options.)

Comment: @cdhowie Gratuitous braces harm maintainability, not improve it. Same with gratuitous newlines and parens, etc. In all cases, there's a balance.

Comment: @blm Disagree. When the line gets changed to `if (something) a = 2; b = 3;` there is suddenly a defect. Yes, the developer should have known better, but if the line were `if (something) { a = 2; }` then the code wouldn't have been damaged by maintenance in the first place.

Comment: As the original poster, my only comment is that you are arguing about coding conventions.  The language obviously supports what was posted.  However, if you and your team/organization want to enforce certain conventions that don't allow it, that is fine.  You are also free to provide input to others on why your convention may be, in your mind, superior.  However, I don't think you should be saying that your personal convention is the only way it can/should be done.